# select and append html from external

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

```
$.get("http://example.com/email_"+file+".html", function( data ) {
console.log(data) // loaded correctly
// append something here
});
```

how can I append stuff into my data? I want to select its' class and do append.

Comment: what your data content look like?

Answer (score 1):

```
$.get("http://example.com/email_"+file+".html", function( data ) {
  console.log(data) // loaded correctly
  var $data = $(data);
  $data.find('img').css('border', '1px solid black');
});
```

use jquery to parse the html response and then change attributes or append stuff and so on.

Comment: then how do i append it?

Comment: @AliceXo Where do you want to append(add) it to?